# django pasar parametros por url

Tags: python, django, django-urls

tengo el siguiente problema:

tengo un menu con tres opciones:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a href="pueblo/opcion1" class="nav-link link-dark" aria-current="page">
                    opcion1
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="pueblo/opcion2" class="nav-link link-dark">
                    opcion2
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="pueblo/opcion3" class="nav-link link-dark">
                    opcion3
                  </a>
                </li>
                
              </ul>
```

Cuando clico en una de las tres opciones la url se queda asi:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/pueblo/opcion1
El problema viene si vuelvo a hacer clic en otra opcion la url se queda asi: http://127.0.0.1:8000/pueblo/pueblo/opcion2
se vuelve a escribir "pueblo" ¿de que forma podria hacer para que se pase solo la opcion y no se vuelva a escribir pueblo?
urls.py:

```
path('pueblo/<str:pueblo>',views.pueblo, name='pueblo'),
```

views.py

```
def pueblo(request, pueblo):
    
    activo = establecimientos.objects.filter(pueblo=pueblo)
    context = {'establecimientos_objects':activo}
    return render(request, 'orders/establecimientos.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar las `href`:

```
href="{% url 'pueblo' pueblo='option1' %}"
href="{% url 'pueblo' pueblo='option2' %}"
href="{% url 'pueblo' pueblo='option3' %}"
```

Donde el la primera parte: `'pueblo'` indica el `name` que has puesto en `path('pueblo/<str:pueblo>',views.pueblo, name='pueblo')`

y la segunda parte: `pueblo='option1'` es el valor de `<str:pueblo>`

Answer (score 0):

Nunca pude hacerlo de esta manera, investigue bastante. Logre hacerlo asignandole action al form donde ubicaba la entrada del dato (select, listas, input, etc.) y luego pasarlo por get.

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/392962)